# Environment where everything is escaped automatically

Tags: catcodes

I wan't to use latex to allow users to generate PDF-Reports on the fly. The problem is that a part of the document gets filled with information from the user-side. 
What I'm looking for is an environment in which every symbol can be used without escaping it. I just stumbled over this limitation when using a hashtag and the micro-symbol (µ) from the user side. The hashtag can be somehow handled, but not the micro-symbol.

As an alternative I could imagine using a tool which converts the special symbols to the escaped latex-pendents.

It's quite similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213352/using-newcommand-to-display-user-input-that-may-contain-special-characters-that), but there is no solution for the micro-symbol.

Would be great if someone could give me a hint!

EDIT: Here is an example for a template. The values in the %% will be replaced with some content from the user-side (for example "12.54µm").

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% Imports
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
...
\begin{document}
    \section{%USERTITLE%}
        %USERDESCRIPTION1%: %USERVALUE1%
        %USERDESCRIPTION2%: %USERVALUE2%
        %USERDESCRIPTION3%: %USERVALUE3%
        ...
\end {document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure to understand the requirement. Can you give an example?

Comment: ``\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\%=12 }``?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Manuel! But how does this help concerning my µ-symbol?

Comment: I didn't understand the unicode part. If you mean that the user might want to input certain unicode characters, well, that's just a basic problem in TeX, not related to your problem. With `inputenc` + (`newunicodechar` or `\DeclareUnicodeChar`) or `siunitx` + `\SI{12.54}{\micro\metre}` you would solve that.

Comment: The problem is, that the user does not know anything about tex. They will just enter symbols and don't use the tex escapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to provide a late answer at this point. The easiest way to deal with unicode chars would be to switch your engine to e.g. XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. They handle full UTF-8 input including Greek/Cyrillic characters. The slightly slow-down in PDF creation should be no real drawback nowadays.

If you cannot switch your engine you should consider that it is a very high effort to have a `\DeclareUnicodeChar` for every char that should be inserted. Maybe as a further reference [this TeX.SX post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex).

Another way you described was to write a tool to escape signs for LaTeX. A particular example for such a software can be found [on this wonderful site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23438/124577).

Comment: Thank you TeXnician! That is a great answer! Very helpful :-)